# How to emulate ON DELETE CASCADE?

Tags: constraints, vertica

Is there a way I can emulate the constraints `ON DELETE CASCADE` in Vertica ?
I seem to get the following error :

> ROLLBACK 4229:  ON DELETE actions other than NO ACTION are not supported for foreign key constraints

And I cannot find too much about it in the docs!

Comment: I don't think you can.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC foreign key constraints are only enforced for pre-join projections, if you create one of those then the cascade may take place.